# How can i use sass and 960gs system together on sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, sass, 960.gs

As an experiment I'm going to try use sass and 960gs system together on sinatra, but it occurs many trouble with this. Has nobody any idea what can go wrong in my case?

```
app.rb:
get '/reset.css' do
sass :reset
end
get '/960.css' do
sass :'960gs'
end
get '/main.css' do
sass :main
end
get '/' do
erb :index
end

layout.erb:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/reset.css"  type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/960gs.css"  type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"  type="text/css"  />
```

960gs.sass, reset.sass, main.sass is in views subdirectory, but only main.sass renders whe I run application.

Thanks for help.
Greetings
Z.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've given this answer before but couldn't find it…

My advice, having used the route you've tried above in the past, is to precompile assets such as these. I use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) along with [Guard-SASS](https://github.com/hawx/guard-sass) with a line like:

```
guard 'sass', :input => 'app/views/stylesheets', :output => 'app/public/css', :style => "compressed"
```

and then use normal stylesheet links in the layout. It's easier to manage and faster.

Comment: Hi Iain, Thanks for your answer! Before to follow your answer I choosed to check again all sass files and it was shown to i had lucky, 960gs.sass was invalid. After I have corrected the file rendering became OK. But I learned something new about guard! Greetings /Z

Comment: @user2018759 glad you got it fixed.